# Interface Property name named from myStrings

Tags: javascript, typescript

I typed up a bunch of strings for a project:

```
declare interface IMyWebPartStrings {
  PropertyDamage: string;
  EventWorkRelated: string;
  EmployeeWearingProperPPE: string;
  YourSupervisor: string;
  Region: string;
  Branch: string;
  PositionTitle: string;
  LocationOfEvent: string;
  DateOfIncident: string;
  InvolvedPeople: string;
  EventDetails: string;
  CorrectiveActions: string;
  CorrectiveActionsDetails: string;
  ...
}
```

I am creating an `interface` and it will have all the same names.

When I create the `interface`, is there a way I can name the properties from the myStrings list?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible.

Quick explanation: Interfaces are defined before compilation of the code, but the contents of the myStrings list is only known after, when the code is run (even when you hard-code the value of myStrings, this won't get interpreted until the code is run).